# How to get "public link" of photo uploaded to Facebook album

Tags: c#, facebook, post, sdk, photo

When I upload a photo to a Facebook album I get an ID, (e.g. 239927946070815). How do I get the link to this photo on Facebook, e.g. http://www.facebook.com/#!/photo.php?fbid=239927946070815&set=a.239886702741606.63927.100001608349025&type=1&theater"

I'm currently creating the link through string ops and I've seen solutions which use Regex, but it remains a "brittle" approach. Is there an official spec relating to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you use the facebook C# SDK, try this:

```
public String GetPhotoLink(string photoID)
{
    var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
    dynamic albums = fb.Get("me/albums");
    foreach (dynamic albumInfo in albums.data)
    {
        dynamic photos = fb.Get(albumInfo.id + "/photos");
        foreach (var photo in photos.data)
        {
            if (photo.id == photoID)
            {
                return photo.link;
            }
        }
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I was hoping it would be possible without iterating over all photos but the upside is that this will always work.

Answer (score 0):

this works as well and has the benefit of being simple and fast compared to the above solution.

Obviously alot of time has passed since this was asked and answered, but since this is the first answer to pop up in google I figure it warrants an update.

```
        _api = new FacebookClient(_authToken);
        var getImage = _api.Get("/" + photoId);
```